# options in man document confused me

Tags: linux

i am a linx beginner.the command options often confused me
e.g.
dash and double dash

### let us look at 'man lftp'

```
mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]

-e, --delete             delete files not present at remote site

    --delete-first       delete old files before transferring new ones

    --depth-first        descend into subdirectories before transferring files
```

---

what is -e?

-e ==? --delete

or

-e ==? --delete --delete-first --depth-first

Answer (score 4):

`-e` is the same as `--delete` *only*.

There do not exist short options corresponding to `--delete-first` or `--depth-first`, so those have to be written out in full.